# how to find a property in multi element with same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find a property multi with same class, and for this purpose I use a loop for it, for example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $('.chat-to').length; ++i)
        if($('.chat-to')[i].prop('id') == receiverID)
            return;
```

but in run time if statement throw a error that is 
`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` though when I test it in console with this code `$('.chat-to')[i]` it shows entire tag, I need to know why? thanks.

Comment: Why not just `$('#'+ receiverID)` since id must be unique. Or `document.getElementById(receiverID)`

Comment: I agree with @Karl-AndréGagnon, IDs are must be unique and using jQuery as he says will find it - no need to loop seeking for an id.

Comment: yes but this ID used in a situation that class will change or older ID deleted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('.chat-to')[i]` returns the DOM element, not the jQuery object. You need to use `.eq()` to fetch the jQuery object.

```
for(var i = 0; i < $('.chat-to').length; ++i)
    if($('.chat-to').eq(i).prop('id') == receiverID)
        return;
```

Or, you could just use the plan DOM way of getting the ID:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $('.chat-to').length; ++i)
    if($('.chat-to')[i].id == receiverID)
        return;
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue with this trick:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $('.chat-to').length; ++i) {
        var temp = $('.chat-to')[i];
        if ($(temp).prop('id') == receiverID)
            return;
    }
```